# wcf initialization policy with multiple calls

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I have a question about initializing the wcf service client proxy when I have many calls . 
Lets say I have a process , which connect the server each 5 sec, I don't want to instantiate the service client proxy each 5 sec, so I initialized it the first time and use the same instance all the calls . 
Is that OK , do I miss something here , does the wcf service open and close the connection each 5 sec although its the same instance .

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Client Connection Caching/Pooling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509487/wcf-client-connection-caching-pooling)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [**`ChannelFactory<T>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) So every time we need a proxy we just ask Channel factory to provide a proxy. So it is Channel Factory's responsibility to give you proxy from its internal cache or to create new one.

Link provided by BNL is a good resource and discuss how it helps to achieve the performance.
Also check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx) for example how to use ChannelFactory.